# gVim marks are not working in 64 bit windows 7?

Tags: vim

I mark a line with command ma (in normal mode) and move to some other lines in same file but when I try to jump back to mark a, It doesn't work at all.
Any clue to enable it ?

Comment: enter :marks to display all active marks.  Is your mark one of them?

Comment: yes mark a is listed there.

Comment: what do use to jump back to the mark?  Should be "backtick a".

Comment: yes of course I am using <'a> to jump back.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. All works fine.
Maybe you have installed plugin or options in .vimrc that breaks standard behavior? Try start gvim without any: `gvim -u NONE`

Comment: no it's not working at all.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. The problem has been occurred due to language settings of windows. as keyboard language English(India) was selected instead of English(United States).